# How to remove <ion-footer> in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to hide  if I clicked on search button but there is small problem I couldn't solve it.

**for example this is the part of my footer html code.**

> **Note1:** "search" is a normal variable defined in the first of .ts code with value "false".
>
> **Note2:** If I click the button, There is a function to change it to "true".

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!search">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-input placeholder="Type some thing" [(ngModel)]="variables.chatText" (click)="autoScroll()"></ion-input>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-right color="royal" [disabled]="!variables.chatText" (click)="sendChat(variables.chatText)" >Send<ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

when I want to hide it, my page shown such as this picture. How can I solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Post your typescript code in the component (specifically where you set the `search` property)

Comment: @Rastographics its a normal variable. I just change his value from "false" to "true". this is the function after click on search button : showSearchBar(){this.search=true;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you can see in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#resizing-the-content):

> If the height of `ion-header`, `ion-footer` or `ion-tabbar` changes
>   dynamically, `content.resize()` has to be called in order to update the
>   layout of Content.

```
class YourPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  search: boolean = false;

  toggleToolbar() {
    // Toggle the footer
    this.search = !this.search;

    // Update the size of the content
    this.content.resize();
  }
}
```